# How to convert ndjson data into numpy to extract image data?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, ndjson

Following the [Google's doodle dataset](https://github.com/googlecreativelab/quickdraw-dataset) I would like to know how to get the numpy 28x28 image data out of a `.ndjson` file (just the image data).

> I am aware that they also provide the dataset in a numpy version but I am facing a similar issue with another dataset similar to Google´s one which only has the simplified `.ndjson` files.

Comment: Do you want raw ndjson or simplified drawings files in ndjson?

Comment: So I basically want to use the simplified ```.ndjson``` files to generate the numpy arrays. Thanks for commenting :D